# Scala mongodb transaction: How to rollback?

Tags: mongodb, scala, transactions

There is an example of Scala mongodb transaction:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver/blob/r2.4.0/driver/src/it/scala/org/mongodb/scala/DocumentationTransactionsExampleSpec.scala

But it's not clear how to rollback the transaction in case of failure.

Here is the code I copied from official example but modified a bit to make the transaction fail in the second insertion (inserting 2 documents with same ids), but problem is that the first document is persisted, and I need the WHOLE transaction to be rolled back.

```
import org.mongodb.scala._
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

object Application extends App {

  val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27018")

  val database = mongoClient.getDatabase("hr")
  val employeesCollection = database.getCollection("employees")

  // Implicit functions that execute the Observable and return the results
  val waitDuration = Duration(5, "seconds")
  implicit class ObservableExecutor[T](observable: Observable[T]) {
    def execute(): Seq[T] = Await.result(observable.toFuture(), waitDuration)
  }

  implicit class SingleObservableExecutor[T](observable: SingleObservable[T]) {
    def execute(): T = Await.result(observable.toFuture(), waitDuration)
  }


  updateEmployeeInfoWithRetry(mongoClient).execute()

  Thread.sleep(3000)

  /// -------------------------


  def updateEmployeeInfo(database: MongoDatabase, observable: SingleObservable[ClientSession]): SingleObservable[ClientSession] = {
    observable.map(clientSession => {
      val eventsCollection = database.getCollection("events")

      val transactionOptions = TransactionOptions.builder().readConcern(ReadConcern.SNAPSHOT).writeConcern(WriteConcern.MAJORITY).build()
      clientSession.startTransaction(transactionOptions)

      eventsCollection.insertOne(clientSession, Document("_id" -> "123", "employee" -> 3, "status" -> Document("new" -> "Inactive", "old" -> "Active")))
        .subscribe((res: Completed) => println(res))

      // THIS SHOULD FAIL, SINCE  THERE IS ALREADY DOCUMENT WITH ID = 123, but PREVIOUS OPERATION SHOULD BE ALSO ROLLED BACK.
      // I COULD NOT FIND THE WAY HOW TO ROLLBACK WHOLE TRANSACTION IF ONE OF OPERATIONS FAILED
      eventsCollection.insertOne(clientSession, Document("_id" -> "123", "employee" -> 3, "status" -> Document("new" -> "Inactive", "old" -> "Active")))
        .subscribe((res: Completed) => println(res))
      // I'VE TRIED VARIOUS THINGS (INCLUDING CODE BELOW)
//        .subscribe(new Observer[Completed] {
//          override def onNext(result: Completed): Unit = println("onNext")
//
//          override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = clientSession.abortTransaction()
//
//          override def onComplete(): Unit = println("complete")
//        })
      clientSession
    })
  }

  def commitAndRetry(observable: SingleObservable[Completed]): SingleObservable[Completed] = {
    observable.recoverWith({
      case e: MongoException if e.hasErrorLabel(MongoException.UNKNOWN_TRANSACTION_COMMIT_RESULT_LABEL) => {
        println("UnknownTransactionCommitResult, retrying commit operation ...")
        commitAndRetry(observable)
      }
      case e: Exception => {
        println(s"Exception during commit ...: $e")
        throw e
      }
    })
  }

  def runTransactionAndRetry(observable: SingleObservable[Completed]): SingleObservable[Completed] = {
    observable.recoverWith({
      case e: MongoException if e.hasErrorLabel(MongoException.TRANSIENT_TRANSACTION_ERROR_LABEL) => {
        println("TransientTransactionError, aborting transaction and retrying ...")
        runTransactionAndRetry(observable)
      }
    })
  }

  def updateEmployeeInfoWithRetry(client: MongoClient): SingleObservable[Completed] = {

    val database = client.getDatabase("hr")
    val updateEmployeeInfoObservable: Observable[ClientSession] = updateEmployeeInfo(database, client.startSession())
    val commitTransactionObservable: SingleObservable[Completed] =
      updateEmployeeInfoObservable.flatMap(clientSession => clientSession.commitTransaction())
    val commitAndRetryObservable: SingleObservable[Completed] = commitAndRetry(commitTransactionObservable)

    runTransactionAndRetry(commitAndRetryObservable)
  }
}
```

How to rollback the whole transaction if any operation failed?

Comment: Are you inserting both documents as part of the same transaction? Can you elaborate on your scenario? The `_id` index is always unique, so if there are two independent inserts with the same `_id` only the first one will succeed. It sounds unusual to be creating documents with duplicate keys in the same transaction, however if any operation in a transaction fails the transaction will abort and discard all data changes made in the transaction. Transaction commit/rollback support is a server feature in MongoDB 4.0+; your application does not explicitly rollback individual changes.

Comment: @Stennie I insert two documents with same ids just to check whether the transaction will be rolled back. "your application does not explicitly rollback individual changes." - so that's the question, I did not find the way to explicitly rollback transaction in case of failure.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the actual code you are testing? Assuming you have correctly set up a transaction, if the transaction aborts (for example, on a duplicate key exception) the changes in that transaction will not be committed. If both inserts are part of the same transaction, I would expect the transaction to fail without committing any changes. Your current description sounds like expected behaviour for two documents that are independently inserted with the same `_id` value: the first will succeed and subsequent attempts will fail with a duplicate key exception.

Comment: @Stennie I edited my question with an example, I would be very thankful if you can shed some light on that.

Answer (score 1):

From the source code of the Scala driver at https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver/blob/r2.6.0/driver/src/main/scala/org/mongodb/scala/ClientSessionImplicits.scala

It appears that there is an `abortTransaction()` method defined along with `commitTransaction()`.

In another note, currently a single replica set transaction in MongoDB 4.0 will be automatically aborted if it's not committed within 60 seconds (configurable). In the [MongoDB Multi-Document ACID Transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-multi-document-acid-transactions-general-availability) blog post:

> By default, MongoDB will automatically abort any multi-document transaction that runs for more than 60 seconds. Note that if write volumes to the server are low, you have the flexibility to tune your transactions for a longer execution time.